# WSO2 DSS 3.1.1: How to pass schema name into a query?

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server

I have multiple identical schema in my Oracle database and I want to run similar reports for each passing the schema name as a parameter. This doesn't seem to work in WSO2 so what can I do?

Here's my simple example: lets say I have a schema/user set up for each of my customer organisations (CustA, CustB, ...) and I write a query to return a list of userids and their real user names.

Assuming I'm logged in as a report user granted access to the necessary tables I could use sqlplus to run the following to get the user list from the users_profile table for customer A:

```
    select user_name, full_user_name from custa.users_profile;
```

Also prompting for the customer name, the following works just fine with sqlplus:

```
    select user_name, full_user_name from &customer..users_profile;
```

Now, how do I get something similar to work with WSO2 dataservices? Following is my XML definition including a named parameter :customer that doesn't work for me. Please can anybody help? Thanks.

```
<data name="UserService">
   <config id="Customer">
      <property name="driverClassName">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</property>
      <property name="url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@v103/serena</property>
      <property name="username">wso2</property>
      <property name="password">wso2</property>
   </config>
   <query id="UsersProfile" useConfig="Customer">
      <sql>select user_name, full_user_name from :customer.users_profile</sql>
      <result element="Users" rowName="User">
         <element column="user_name" name="user_name" xsdType="string"/>
         <element column="full_user_name" name="full_user_name" xsdType="string"/>
      </result>
      <param name="customer" sqlType="STRING"/>
   </query>
   <operation name="UsersProfile">
      <call-query href="UsersProfile">
         <with-param name="customer" query-param="customer"/>
      </call-query>
   </operation>
</data>
```

Comment: Ok, I finally figured it out and the answer is to use "QUERY_STRING" rather than STRING as the sqlType. I was originally working with WSO2 DSS 2.5.1 and then with 3.0.1 (not 3.1.1 as stated) and it seems that the latest version includes this new type that allows direct string substitution into the query.

Comment: Just to clarify further, it wouldn't work to just pass the schema into :customer and expect it to concatenate with the table name. My solution was to replace ":customer.users_profile" with ":customerusersprofile" and use <param name="customeruserprofile" sqlType="QUERY_STRING". My client prcess then passed the string like CUSTA.USERS_PROFLE.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to upgrade to WSO2 DSS 3.1.1 and user the QUERY_STRING type. See my comment for more info. Sorry to waste everybody's time!